# SQL error: login failed for user 'domain\user'

Tags: sql

I have looked at many posts on this issue, but for me all the proposed solutions didnt work. I am trying to access a database with a remote user, so I am setting the connection credentials as needed. I get the error as shown in the subject of this post. I have checked all the permissions, things like that, windows/sql authentication, etc. Any quick ideas of another potential problem?

Comment: Kindly refer to the below link for your solution. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40980/login-failed-for-user-domain-username-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the user has the permission, and you have entered the password correctly as you say, then another thing to look at would be to ensure the user is authorized to access the database remotely.

Comment: I believe that was already the case. In the server properties > connectoins, allow remote connections to this server is indeed checked off, unless there is another location I need to check for this or within the users properties